# oracle Reading Directly from a URL code not working properly

Tags: java, url

I'm trying to learn how to download images and files from a website trough a java program. The code below is copied from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html. This program is supposed to display the html file code from the url provided.

Quoted from the site:"When you run the program, you should see, scrolling by in your command window, the HTML commands and textual content from the HTML file located at http://www.oracle.com/. "

My problem is that it works for some websites, but not for interfacelift.com. It doesn't display anything for that website. I'm trying to figure out why.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL oracle = new URL("http://interfacelift.com/");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by '..it works ... not for interfacelift.com.'? Of cause no javascript related changes on the page would be performed.

Comment: Quoted from the site:"When you run the program, you should see, scrolling by in your command window, the HTML commands and textual content from the HTML file located at http://www.oracle.com/. "

Comment: You can use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net) which simulates a browser and even interprets javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the site is refusing to send you any content because it doesn't recognise that you're using a web browser.  Some web sites don't appreciate automated web scrapers such as your program attempting to read their web pages and so choose to block them.

When I tried using Python to make the same request, I got a 403 Forbidden error.  I imagine your Java application is getting much the same error:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib2
>>> urllib2.urlopen("http://interfacelift.com/").read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 444, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: Ok thanks a bunch guys. After following your hints I found out its because setRequestProperty had to be used after creating a URLconnection object like so:                                        URL url = new URL("http://interfacelift.com");
        URLConnection hc = url.openConnection();
        hc.setRequestProperty(blablabla etc